# Total of Clients SUM

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Hope you all are well.

Im trying to count the total SUM of different client names for example

```
Michael
Michael
Michael
Jose
Maria
```

Total Different Names = 3

Would appreciate any pointers guys,

Much Love!

Comment: Pivot may solve your task. PS. It is the count of unique names, not sum...

Comment: Thank you Akina for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an array formula and you will need to hit **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** when you've finished typing

```
=SUM(1/COUNTIF(A1:A5,A1:A5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks SQL Temp im giving it a try as im typing. Will share results!

Comment: Can I share my Excel file?

Comment: Whys that? @MichaelRichardson

Comment: So im changing =SUM(1/COUNTIF(A1:A5,A1:A5)) to =SUM(1/COUNTIF(A2:A500,A2:A500)) as the names are in that column and cell range but keep getting "1" as result and when reducing the range i get DIV/0. But, when using your formula in a new column with freshly input data it counts perfectly.  Thought you seeing the file might help clarify. Thank you.

Comment: Done, was not using Ctrl+shift+Enter after editing the formula. Thank you again for your time. All the best!